# I am trying to display the index value of strings which I have obtained using the input function

Tags: python, infinite-loop

```
index=0

while True:
    stri=input("enter the strings : ")
    if stri=="Exit" or stri=="exit":
        break
    for indexes in stri:
        letter=stri[index]
        print(index, letter)
        index=index+1
```

After displaying the index value of the first string entered it is showing an error

```
    enter the strings : abcdfg
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 f
5 g
enter the strings : qwerty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "len.py", line 10, in <module>
    letter=stri[index]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

this is the error I get

Comment: arrange you code indentation

Comment: and show the full code with the traceback

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you don't need to keep the index use the pointer that you are using for writing the string charcters

```
# index=0

while True:
    stri=input("enter the strings : ")
    if stri=="Exit" or stri=="exit":# you can directly use lower()
        break
    for indexes in range(len(stri)):
        letter=stri[indexes]
        print(indexes+1, letter)
```

Alternate solution

```
while True:
    stri=input("enter the strings : ")
    if stri=="Exit" or stri=="exit":# you can directly use lower()
        break
    index=0
    for indexes in range(len(stri)):
        letter=stri[index]
        print(index+1, letter)
        index+=1
```

Comment: @BenyGj what are you saying?

Comment: you have edited your answer after you respond i was the first on this answer

Answer (score 1):

As you are already looping through the string, you don't need the extra index:

```
while True:
    stri=input("enter the strings : ")
    if stri=="Exit" or stri=="exit":
        break
    for index, letter in enumerate(stri):
        print(index, letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
while True:
    stri=input("enter the strings : ")
    if stri.lower() == 'exit':
        break
    for index, value in enumerate(stri):
        print(index, " "+ value)
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to init the index after each input

```
while True:
    index=0
    stri=input("enter the strings : ")
    if stri=="Exit" or stri=="exit":
        break
    for indexes in stri:
        letter=stri[index]
        print(index, letter)
        index=index+1
```

Comment: you need to reset index each iteration